# Get file path with dynamic path inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, readfile, fs

I need to create file from directory like following

application/user**xxx**.txt/manifest.txt

The path is constant **except the userxxx** which can be **any alpha numeric**

```
/application/ 
       user12.txt
       newfile.txt
       newFile2.txt
```

There is **only one** file which start with user...

I think of using the which is currently not working..

```
 fs.readdir('c://application', function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
```

and then get all the files under the application 
and search for file which start with userabcd1234.txt and when I find it do the read file like following

`readFile('application/userabcd1234/manifest.txt')`

There is **no** two files inside **application** which start with **/user.** just one but after the user. and before the third '/manifest.txt' can be any **random** alpha numeric.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Are you getting error or empty file list?

Comment: @hassansin - Now I able to see the files(I dont know why before not ) I just changed the code to use var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../../../../');

fs.readdir(filePath,function(err, files){
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    files.forEach( function (file){
        console.log( file );
    });
});

Comment: @hassansin - my question now is from all the files how u suggest to get the file path which starts with user  and  end with .txt?

Comment: just iterate through the directory names and check for the condition 'file.indexOf('user')===0'. This will give you the userxxx directory name.

Comment: @hassansin - can you provide the complete example as answer ?Thanks in advance sir!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../your path to application folder');

fs.readdir(filePath, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        if (file.indexOf('user') === 0) {
            var relFilePath = filePath + '/' + file + '/manifest.txt';
            fs.readFile(relFilePath,'utf8', function read(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```